# Integrating Angular5 in an existing Laravel project with blade

Tags: angular, laravel, frontend, laravel-blade

I am worried about an issue refered to the inetgration of a frontend framework in my current project.

I'm involved in a development project based on Laravel in which i'm using the Laravel template system (Blade) for the views and frontend logic. I just realized that I really need to start using a frontend framework due to complex increment of the tasks and client logic.

I'm really lost about it and I don't really know where is the best way. I just thought about using angular5 to build the new features. I mean, develop some services (REST) with laravel and use them with angular to develop the new views of that features with angular components.
I think there's no problem about that. However, the main issue is, if I started using Angular for new features and views in the client stack, how would it be the transition between the views loaded just with laravel and the views loaded with angular? I mean, would it be a problem transitions between two urls, one rendered with blade templates and other loaded with angular?

I don't know if I explained myself the best way. To put in a nutshell, I just want to integrate a frontend framework in my current project in which I'm using HTML+CSS+Vanilla JS without any framework. In fact, I don't know if angular is what I need, could you give some advice about that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Angular5 is mostly a front-end engine. Which means if you include the angular bundled library (and app) javascript files in `index.html`. It'll work with any engine including backend engine ex. Laravel.

I had Laravel and Angular app before. What I did is to use angular mostly for the widgets (or component) building. Ex. creating more tags, `<app-room [prop]="abc" />`. This is more like redo the HTML part in a much nicer way. Don't you agree?

When it comes to the routing, especially backend routing, I still heavily uses Laravel, because it has all session controlled route protection etc. You just need to make sure whenever it needs angular component, it'll require javascript library loaded from `index.html` template, either it's parent or derived template.

This is easy to understand if you look at the production source code of angular 5 where you can see the `index.html` only tries to load 4-5 javascript files compiled from angular 5. (Try `npm run build` and study `/dist` folder afterward.)

Now in order to develop on these two systems at the same time, it's better you keep both in seperate folder, ex. `laravel` and `angular`. Because both use its own packaging system. The connection is that the compilation result of angular should be sitting in the asset folder of laravel. This is much easier if we are dealing with angularJS 1 below. But with angular 2 and up, it'll be messy if you just copy everything under asset folder.

I do not think it's that complicated, but to streamline the process really depends on what you want to do with angular since I assume you already have big plans for using laravel.

Comment: Note: one thing you should keep in mind is that Laravel carries page state, ex. session. But in general, Angular doesn't. This is very important when you mixing them.

Comment: I think I understood your comment. I would like to appreciate it. I'm really in a big trouble with this because I don't really know how to mix my current project and add it angular to front end.
So you think using angular 5, I just need to add angular libraries to my index.html, but how can I do it? Is it possible to load Angular in my project that way and use it in my html files (Blade)? SO if I undertood it properly, Angular compilation of views should save it in the assets directory, in which I have my blade views?
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: When I say mix, I don't really mean to have them sitting under same folder. Instead you can just continue with your seprate `Laravel` and `Angular5` folder. Just do your best to get both working seperately. After that you can deploy angular5 dist folder under Laravel assets folder